# Access custom view properties after inflation in Android

Tags: android, view, android-inflate

I have an activity with a LinearLayout which I want to add multiple buttons to. These buttons are Custom Views which I inflate. I need to add these custom buttons to my Linear Layout in code. All of this works.

What I cant get to work is to use findViewById in my custom button after I have inflated it so I can set its properties. findViewById returns null.

**Activity Code:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.levelbrowser);        
    LinearLayout uttonLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ButtonLayout);                
    LevelBrowserButton button1 = new LevelBrowserButton(this, "Level 1");
    ButtonLayout.addView(button1);
}
```

**Custom Button Code:**

```
public LevelBrowserButton(Context context, String name) 
{
    super(context);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);                 
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.levelbrowser_button, this);

    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.NameTextView);
    // nameTextView = null!
    NameTextView.setText("test"); // This will throw an exception

}
```

I have read through many posts on the internet and still cant get this to work. I have also tried "Clean..." in Eclipse on my project.

Comment: Have you tried type casting the view after infating to the outer layout like LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.levelbrowser_button, this);

Comment: I tried it but it makes no difference.

Comment: inflater.inflate(R.layout.levelbrowser_button, this);. Im not sure about this line as you are suppose to give the viewgroup object you are trying inflate to. Instead you are passing this object. If this code is inside the activity, it will be the activity object. Just a thought.